# Construction of real numbers, multiplication definition (Dedekind)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers

Definition:

Let $r,s∈ℝ$.

If $r>_ℝ0$ and ,$s>_ℝ0$ then the product of $r$ and $s$ is:
$r·_ℝs=\{p·_ℚq:p∈r\:and\:q∈s\}∪\{q∈ℚ:q≤_ℚ0\}$

If $r>_ℝ0$ and , $s≤_ℝ0$ then the product of $r$ and $s$ is:
$r·_ℝs=\{p·_ℚq:p∈r\:and\:q∈s\}$

Now since i'm reading "Classic Set Theory: For Guided **Independent** Study" it would make too much sense to give a complete definition for this operation, so the definition for $r≤_ℝ0$ is left as an exercise without solution ‍♂️ (classic math books style), does anyone know the answer to this question? i googled it and used Enderton's book on set theory and i only find the definition using the absolute value, but in this book only addition has been introduced so fare.
I would like a definition that is somewhat similar to the one above. Any help please? I tried but i can't really come up with it

Comment: Maybe useful Ethan Bloch, [The real numbers and real analysis (Springer, 2011)](https://books.google.it/books?id=r0qcU9U2_I4C&pg=PA33)

Comment: The ordering on Dedekind cuts is simpler than any of their other structure: we set $L_0\le L_1$ iff every element of $L_0$ is $\le$ every element of $L_1$. (This follows the convention that "Dedekind cut" means "downwards-closed set of rationals," which it seems is what you're doing.) In particular, thinking of the embedding of the rationals into the Dedekind cuts $r\le 0$ iff every element of $r$ is $\le 0$. Does this not work with the approach the text takes? If so I'm surprised it hasn't been defined already.

Answer (score 0):

The ordering on the Dedekind cuts is really the simplest aspect of their structure, and should be understood before diving into their arithmetic. (That's not a criticism of you, but rather the textbook - in my opinion they really shouldn't talk about arithmetic of Dedekind cuts before covering the ordering.) It's just the following: $L_0\le L_1$ iff every element of $L_0$ is $\le$ every element of $L_1$ (with the latter "$\le$" being the usual ordering on the rationals).

This reflects the intuition behind Dedekind cuts as "approximations" of real numbers by rational numbers. We think of a cut $L$ as representing the real $\sup(L)$, and we have $$\sup(A)\le \sup(B)\iff \forall x\in A,y\in B(x\le y).$$

And comparing Dedekind cuts and *rationals* is no harder: the same intuition holds, and since  we identify the rational $q$ with the cut $\{p\in\mathbb{Q}: p< q\}$ we get $L\le q$ iff each element of $L$ is $<q$.